# "==!!! Resulted fork bomb" error using Perl VimDebug

Tags: perl, debugging, vim, ubuntu

I using this VimDebug: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=663
And after I press F12 for start debug session I have long stack trace with error like:

```
==!!! Resulted for bomb which slowly wil ...
```

And CPU go to 100%...

Some one know what it may be?
Thank you for ahead.